# ios format specifier: how to NSLog 0x%x in iOS 4.2

Tags: ios-4.2, nslog, format-specifiers

```
 NSMutableArray *foo = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:12];
 NSLog(@" foo is 0x%x", foo);  // worked in XCode 4.0 to return the hex address of this variable
```

Now it gives compiler warning:

**Conversion specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'NSMutableArray'**

How do I get output like "foo is 0x53a6d0" for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer (with 30 characters) it's:  %p